# Wrong property values in Component.onCompleted

Tags: qt, qml

My problem is the following: I have a custom QML object based on a Rectangle, and I need to execute some javascript function with the width & height of this object when it's created.
To do that, I use Component.onCompleted to execute the javascript but in this function the width and height properties are wrong (like 0;0 or 0;-30), as if they were not yet created.

Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

import "js/kloggr.js" as Game

Rectangle {
    property var kloggr: undefined

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        // outputs the right values (about 400;600)
        onClicked: console.log(width+";"+height);
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Game.kloggr = this;
        kloggr = new Game.Kloggr(width, height);
        console.log(width+";"+height); // outputs 0;-30
    }
}
```

This object is created like this:

```
Kloggr {
    id: kloggr

    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: pauseBtn.top
}
```

(I've removed the irrelevant parts of the code)

So what did I do wrong, or what could I do to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out it if was a bug or something but I found a workaround: instead of using Component.onCompleted I used onVisibleChanged:

```
onVisibleChanged: {
    if (visible && kloggr === undefined) {
        Game.kloggr = this;
        kloggr = new Game.Kloggr(width, height);
    }
}
```

It seems that the width and height properties are only valid when the object is set to visible...
Thank you @yekmen for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to set the width and height of your Rectangle ...

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import "js/kloggr.js" as Game

Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    property var kloggr: undefined

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        // outputs the right values (about 400;600)
        onClicked: console.log(width+";"+height);
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Game.kloggr = this;
        kloggr = new Game.Kloggr(width, height);
        console.log(width+";"+height); // outputs 0;-30
        //now h + w = 300
    }
}
```

If your use anchors, change your Rectangle by Item, for exemple

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import "js/kloggr.js" as Game

Item{
    //without W and Height if you don't use the designer, if you use the designer you should set a default size

    property var kloggr: undefined
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill : parent
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            // outputs the right values (about 400;600)
            onClicked: console.log(width+";"+height);
       }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            Game.kloggr = this;
            kloggr = new Game.Kloggr(width, height);
            console.log(width+";"+height); // outputs 0;-30
       }
  }//end of rectangle

} //end of item
```

Comment: I cannot set a fixed width and height for my object because it adapts to the screen, that's why I used anchors to place it. I tried changing from Rectangle to Item but it had the same problem/bug. I found a workaround finally and I'll post a solution but thank you very much for your help